# kernel update via /dev/mtd

Tags: linux, embedded, kernel

I'm working on embedded device where kernel image is stored inside /dev/mtd4 part of flash.
I would like to update this kernel without Uboot.

How is it possible ?
I was trying to call:

```
echo ./kernel.bin > /dev/mtdblock4
```

but it doesn't work. Stored data are not recognized as kernel in next boot.

Comment: You probably want `cat` rather than `echo`, e.g. `cat ./kernel.bin > /dev/mtdblock4 `

Comment: Yes of course. I mentioned it when I've found ./kernel.bin sting written in my /dev/mtd... cat ./kernel.bin > /dev/mtdblock4 works perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should at least be `cat kernel.bin >  /dev/mtdblock4` but that probably won't work neither.

And it depends upon how your kernel is actually loaded (what is the bootloader).

Comment: It works. I mentioned the failure it when I've found ./kernel.bin string written in my /dev/mtd... cat ./kernel.bin > /dev/mtdblock4 works perfect.

Comment: I had to -1 this, as for NAND-based devices (the majority), you have to erase the flash before writing to it; simply writing to it does not yield the correct results. The other answers here describe the correct approaches.

Comment: That erasing is probably the job of the device driver. When you see a file system it is irrelevant

Comment: It is worth noting however, that the device driver operating in the booted kernel *may not* have sufficiently detailed awareness of the hardware, bad block scheme, etc, to be safely used for writing.  And in other cases it may.  This is basically a "well, let's see if the simple approach works on this one" attempt.

Comment: This is bad advice! You should never write to flash without first deleting it!. @Luke's answer is a much better smarter way of rewriting the kernel image

Answer (score 10):

You should use the [mtdutils](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/MTD_Utilities) tool flashcp :

```
flashcp -v ./kernel.bin /dev/mtd4
```

flashcp will take care of the erasing, writing, and verifying which cat won't do.
Note that is works with the char driver and not the block driver. -v is for verbose operation

Comment: On my NAND flash, `flashcp` broke my rootfs while `flash_eraseall`+`nandwrite -p` worked. - maybe we should care about the tool description "Copies data into NOR flash"?

Answer (score 4):

I've never used flashcp. Where can I get it? I use flash_erase or flash_eraseall and then nandwrite. If you don't have these utilities, you can get the source [here](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/source.html) and build them for your target.

To update my system, I use:

```
# /usr/bin/flash_erase /dev/mtd3
# /usr/bin/nandwrite -m -p /dev/mtd3 /uImage
```

Is this NAND flash? If so, I don't think that echo or cat are going to properly skip bad blocks for you.

Answer (score 0):

To update the different mtd blocks, I use following routine:

```
# flash_eraseall /dev/mtd3
# dd if="kernel.bin" of=/dev/mtd3 bs=16k conv=sync
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have a device where I update the kernel image and use uBoot.
My workflow is:

- I transfer the new imagefile to the devices tmp directory
- I erase the flash mtd directory:

  flash_eraseall /dev/mtd3
- then I copy from tmp to flash directory (/tmp/ --> /dev/mtd3)

  flashcp /tmp/uImage /dev/mtd3

I hope this helps,
regards